# Does number pipe number:'1.0-0' rounds the number?

Tags: angular

I was using number:'1.0-0' to hide any decimal places.
Does it round off the number coz I have heard some say it does if it does then that would be a problem for me.

```
{{file?.progress | number:'1.0-0'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will round**, as mentioned in angular docs:

If no parameters are specified, the function rounds off to the nearest value using this rounding method. The behavior differs from that of the JavaScript Math.round() function. In the following case for example, the pipe rounds down where Math.round() rounds up:

```
-2.5 | number:'1.0-0'
> -3
Math.round(-2.5)
> -2
```

https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe